# Turmoil, yet Balance

Tags: discussion

While there have been a bit of turmoil on Buddhism SE the last couple of days/weeks, I want to point out, that our [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism) stats, are quite good looking. Take a look below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this and I think the two things are related. One of the other moderators termed this kind of thing "growing pains" and I think it might be. Our site is now a successful stack exchange site and it is attracting a widening user base. As such it gone from quite a cozy environment were we all know each other to one where we are getting unfamiliar users with controversial opinions and/or less familiarity with our be nice policy.

It's a challenge for all users and one we are trying to work through. But we are all human beings with our human failings and I know we will get it wrong time and time again. But I hope we do manage to keep things going in a positive direction. I have faith that we will.

Comment: These are some good reflections and points. The site is evolving. No one really knows into what. Let's see what the future brings. I realized by reading Thiagos answer in the chat, that I used to believe the site was a buddhist site, but it's really not. It's a site "about" Buddhism as Thiago points out, meaning that it's not a Sangha.